# Не выполняется код после второго запроса на сервер

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, express

Всем привет.
Делаю два запроса на сервер с помощью $.post. После выполнения первого запроса вызываю второй запрос, передавая полученную информацию из первого запроса.
Проблема заключается в том что после выполнения второго запроса не выполняется код.
Второй запрос возвращает данные, проверял.

Запросы на сервер.

```
$("#start_search").click(function () {
        $.post("/getLinks", {
                searchText: $('#searchText').val(),
                picSize: $('input[name="pic"]:checked').val(),
                typeFile: $('input[name="file"]:checked').val(),
                clicks: $('#numberOfPics').val()
        },
        function (data) {
            //Работает нормально
            console.log('Done!')
            let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            for (let arr of json[0].arrs){
                for (let path of arr[0]){
                    $.post("/setImg", {
                        path: path
                    }),
                    function (res){
                        //Не работает совсем, чтобы я здесь не делал
                        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)))
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

После выполнения первого запроса все нормально, выполняется второй запрос, но после его завершения код не работает.

Второй запрос.

```
app.post("/setImg",  (req, res) => {
    let filepath = req.body.path;
    BD.start(filepath, function (err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        res.json([{
            result: result
        }])
    })
})
```

BD.start

```
function SetToImgDB (filepath, callback){
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO imgs (filepath) VALUES ('${filepath}')`, (err, results) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        createObject(results.insertId, function (err, result) {
            if (err) return callback(err)
            return callback(null, result);
        });
    })
}

function createObject (id, callback) {
    connection.query(`insert into objects (date, img_src, origin, preview, rating) values ('${(new Date()).toISOString().slice(0,19).replace('T', ' ')}', '${id}', '0', '${id}', '0')`, (err, results) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, results.insertId);
    });
}

function start (filepath, callback){
    SetToImgDB(filepath, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        return callback(null, result)
    });
}

module.exports = {
    start,
}
```

Comment: а что значит "*не выполняется код.*" ?  может там ошибка. посмотрите в консоли.. может возвращается не то, что вы думаете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, ошибок никаких не вылазит, проверял как консоль так и сам запрос во вкладке Network, информация возвращается с сервера.

Comment: а что выводит `console.log(res)` ?

Comment: и ещё вопросы, а зачем вы постоянно делаете так  : `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`  ? это же не имеет смысла...... и ещё - зачем цикл если, как я понял, отсылается только одно значение?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в консоль ничего не выводится, в принципе код не работает после второго запроса. 
На счет `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` это делается потому что сервер возвращает объект, и может вернуть несколько значений в зависимости от того какое значение **clicks** передается на сервер, т.е. если я передам 2, то вернет массив из двух строк и т.д.

Comment: если с сервера отдать объект, то он ужЕ будет в response......"*в принципе код не работает после второго запроса*" --- если ответ приходит и статус 200, то и callback должен отрабатывать. по-другому быть не может. Один из вариантов - что либо вы забыли сохранить результат работы и код в браузере не обновился. Либо он в кэше и нужно чистить кэш (а лучше вообще не включать при разработке)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на счет кэша ничего не могу сказать, но код точно обновляется, проверяю во вкладке Source всегда. На счет объекта в response, изначально я просто обращался в этому объекту, но в консоли сыпались ошибки, по этой причине я начал этот объект конвертить в JSON. Ответ приходит и статус 200, да, но callback не работает от слова совсем...

Comment: У вас во втором запросе на фронте функция за скобкой стоит, вне post запроса.То есть она как колбэк не отрабатывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#start_search").click(function () {
    $.post("/getLinks", {
            searchText: $('#searchText').val(),
            picSize: $('input[name="pic"]:checked').val(),
            typeFile: $('input[name="file"]:checked').val(),
            clicks: $('#numberOfPics').val()
    },
    function (data) {
        //Работает нормально
        console.log('Done!')
        let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        for (let arr of json[0].arrs){
            for (let path of arr[0]){
                $.post("/setImg", {
                    path: path
                },
                function (res){
                    //Не работает совсем, чтобы я здесь не делал
                    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)))
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

попробуйте так!